Swift EXC_BAD_ACCESS while Closing the Window
I had a strange problem when closing the Window it threw me this error. This error only happens when I first open the StatusMenuBarIem and close it (No Issue) when I open for the second time it just throws the Dump
BAD ACESS
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)


Here is the sample code for this

import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var statusBarItem: NSStatusItem!
    var burritoOrderWindow: NSWindow?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        
        let statusBar = NSStatusBar.system
        statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)
        statusBarItem.button?.title = ""
        
        let statusBarMenu = NSMenu(title: "8gwifi.org")
        statusBarItem.menu = statusBarMenu
        
        statusBarMenu.addItem(
            withTitle: "Order a burrito",
            action: #selector(AppDelegate.orderABurrito),
            keyEquivalent: "")
            
        statusBarMenu.addItem(
            withTitle: "Cancel burrito order",
            action: #selector(AppDelegate.cancelBurritoOrder),
            keyEquivalent: "")
    }

    @objc func orderABurrito() {
        print("Ordering a burrito!")
        
        // Open another window here
        let window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 300),
                              styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .resizable],
                              backing: .buffered,
                              defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.title = "Burrito Order"
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        
        // Store a reference to the window
        burritoOrderWindow = window
    }

    @objc func cancelBurritoOrder() {
        print("Canceling your order :(")
    }

    // Remainder of AppDelegate…
}

Step to re-procude

Close the Open Window and Again Open it

Added this event
   func windowWillClose(_ notification: Notification) {
        burritoOrderWindow = nil
    }



Added window.isReleasedWhenClosed=false it prevented the crash but second time the window is not comping up ?


hi @Willeke it prevented the crash but now window is not opening second time the object is now not nill

Ignore the Above Solved my Problem You guys are Geniuis Thanks
